# STM32 USB_CDC Firmware to autodetect by Linux

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device, stm32cubemx, usb-otg

We are developing a custom board to control brushless DC motors. The board has STM32F405RGTx. We are now trying to make USB CDC communication work. We generated the code using STM32CubeMX.

Unfortunately, when we plug the board in Linux machine (kernel 4.4.14) USB port it is not detected. However, the kernel gives a message that it detected a new device:

```
sudo dmesg | tail
[346221.900229] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 75 using xhci_hcd
[346222.259132] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 76 using xhci_hcd
[346227.525263] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 96 using xhci_hcd
[346228.765215] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 100 using xhci_hcd
[346230.015198] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 104 using xhci_hcd
[346236.265479] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[346243.515496] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[346250.766546] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
[346252.265563] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 65 using xhci_hcd
[346258.265781] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 89 using xhci_hcd
```

The above is the output after plugging in and out 3 times. As you can see the device is always given a new number and is not completely recognized. Also the message that a new device is detected appears several times for a single time you plug in.

`lsusb` also does not list the device. Can you point me to what section of the STM32 firmware I need to change to fix that so that the device gets listed under `/dev`. You can find the code that I am currently using here: https://github.com/nikonikolov/ODriveFirmware/tree/CDC.

Comment: Do you have the [STM32 Virtual COM Port Driver installed](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-stm32102.html)?

Comment: Isn't that for Windows? I am using Linux. It should have the driver by default

Comment: I can verify that, using ST's USB CDC code for an STM32F105, Linux sees the device without any additional driver installation.  Windows, however, does require ST's COM Port Driver.

Comment: In that case never mind my comment.